# R forecast() specifying h

Tags: r, forecast

I want to use the function `forecast()` from the `forecast` package, but specify something like `h = 1,3,5`. So that I get the forecasts for horizon 1,3 and 5. I do not know how I can achieve that. `h` seems to only accept specifying a singular number, but then it calculates all the forecast horizons until that number, e.g. forecasts with horizon 1 to 5. I only want 1, 3 and 5. The only solution I can come up with is setting `h = 5` and then deleting the columns I don't need. I don't want to do that, however, because in my actual problem I need much higher horizons and calculating all of them would take ages.

Is there a way of doing that?